# ExpandableListView Expand & Collapse

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hi I am New to Android Apps Now I am struck in maintaining the ExpandableListView.. The Groups are not collapsing, Please let me know how to resolve this issue, Thanks in Advance

Below is the Code which I am handling if anything wrong in that code please let me know

```
@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
 super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {

    //if(IsExpanded)
    //{
        if(lastExpandedGroupPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
             onGroupCollapsed(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
             }
        else { super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition); }
    //}

    lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

in if statement insteed of

```
onGroupCollapsed(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
```

try

```
listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
```

or as I see you want to collapse all exept Expanded yu can use something like this

```
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
    int lenght = adapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (i != groupPosition) {
            listView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }
}
```